# How to implement Github style ssh-key based authentication for APIs in Clojure applications?

Tags: authentication, ssh, clojure

How to implement Github style key based authentication for APIs in Clojure applications.
We need a good secure way to have an authetication based on public and private keys to authenticate the data coming in from API calls we are building instead of session-id/oauth-token based authentication.

Is there a good clojure DSL that addresses this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend), which provides nice workflows for handling authentication and  authorization.
[Friend-oauth2](https://github.com/ddellacosta/friend-oauth2) works with Friend and provides a workflow for handling oauth2 authentication.
Is this what you were looking for?